# Update field in a specific column according to counts over previous records using awk

Tags: awk, text-processing

I have to update the first field of the input file below (excluding the two first lines that are a header. The number in the first column before BGL, GLC and LIN is a counter that must be updated in such a way that the counter increases by one for each series of records with the same molecule BCL, GLC and LIN.

Below a small fragment of  my input file (I have 100 files like that one):

```
900 mgdg molecules in water t= 600000.00000 step= 400000000
177255
    1BGL     C5    1   2.709  14.491   1.493
    1BGL     H5    2   2.664  14.412   1.433
    1BGL     O5    3   2.717  14.464   1.627
    1BGL     C1    4   2.599  14.430   1.687
    1BGL     H1    5   2.546  14.350   1.634
    2GLC     O1   23   2.609  14.403   1.823
    2GLC     C1   24   2.675  14.276   1.837
    2GLC    H11   25   2.607  14.204   1.790
    3LIN     C3   44   3.033  14.281   2.268
    3LIN    H31   45   3.136  14.298   2.235
    4LIN     C3   87   3.108  13.927   2.066
    4LIN    H31   88   3.077  13.879   2.159
    1BGL     C5    1   2.709  14.491   1.493
    1BGL     H5    2   2.664  14.412   1.433
    1BGL     O5    3   2.717  14.464   1.627
    1BGL     C1    4   2.599  14.430   1.687
    1BGL     H1    5   2.546  14.350   1.634
    2GLC     O1   23   2.609  14.403   1.823
    2GLC     C1   24   2.675  14.276   1.837
    2GLC    H11   25   2.607  14.204   1.790
    3LIN     C3   44   3.033  14.281   2.268
    3LIN    H31   45   3.136  14.298   2.235
    4LIN     C3   87   3.108  13.927   2.066
    4LIN    H31   88   3.077  13.879   2.159
etc
    1BGL     C5    1   2.709  14.491   1.493
    1BGL     H5    2   2.664  14.412   1.433
    1BGL     O5    3   2.717  14.464   1.627
    1BGL     C1    4   2.599  14.430   1.687
    1BGL     H1    5   2.546  14.350   1.634
    2GLC     O1   23   2.609  14.403   1.823
    2GLC     C1   24   2.675  14.276   1.837
    2GLC    H11   25   2.607  14.204   1.790
    3LIN     C3   44   3.033  14.281   2.268
    3LIN    H31   45   3.136  14.298   2.235
    4LIN     C3   87   3.108  13.927   2.066
    4LIN    H31   88   3.077  13.879   2.159
etc
20389SOL     OW77253   0.644  14.144   5.376
20389SOL    HW177254   0.712  14.203   5.344
20389SOL    HW277255   0.577  14.201   5.413
   6.36535  23.37625  12.09434
```

I want to have as output:

```
900 mgdg molecules in water t= 600000.00000 step= 400000000
177255
    1BGL     C5    1   2.709  14.491   1.493
    1BGL     H5    2   2.664  14.412   1.433
    1BGL     O5    3   2.717  14.464   1.627
    1BGL     C1    4   2.599  14.430   1.687
    1BGL     H1    5   2.546  14.350   1.634
    1GLC     O1   23   2.609  14.403   1.823
    1GLC     C1   24   2.675  14.276   1.837
    1GLC    H11   25   2.607  14.204   1.790
    1LIN     C3   44   3.033  14.281   2.268
    1LIN    H31   45   3.136  14.298   2.235
    1LIN     C3   87   3.108  13.927   2.066
    1LIN    H31   88   3.077  13.879   2.159
    2BGL     C5    1   2.709  14.491   1.493
    2BGL     H5    2   2.664  14.412   1.433
    2BGL     O5    3   2.717  14.464   1.627
    2BGL     C1    4   2.599  14.430   1.687
    2BGL     H1    5   2.546  14.350   1.634
    2GLC     O1   23   2.609  14.403   1.823
    2GLC     C1   24   2.675  14.276   1.837
    2GLC    H11   25   2.607  14.204   1.790
    2LIN     C3   44   3.033  14.281   2.268
    2LIN    H31   45   3.136  14.298   2.235
    2LIN     C3   87   3.108  13.927   2.066
    2LIN    H31   88   3.077  13.879   2.159
etc
  900BGL     C5    1   2.709  14.491   1.493
  900BGL     H5    2   2.664  14.412   1.433
  900BGL     O5    3   2.717  14.464   1.627
  900BGL     C1    4   2.599  14.430   1.687
  900BGL     H1    5   2.546  14.350   1.634
  900GLC     O1   23   2.609  14.403   1.823
  900GLC     C1   24   2.675  14.276   1.837
  900GLC    H11   25   2.607  14.204   1.790
  900LIN     C3   44   3.033  14.281   2.268
  900LIN    H31   45   3.136  14.298   2.235
  900LIN     C3   87   3.108  13.927   2.066
  900LIN    H31   88   3.077  13.879   2.159
etc
20389SOL     OW77253   0.644  14.144   5.376
20389SOL    HW177254   0.712  14.203   5.344
20389SOL    HW277255   0.577  14.201   5.413
   6.36535  23.37625  12.09434
```

I mostly use scripts like that, but this case is more complicated and this script is useless. I know that I should prbably use counter, but how to print this if I have different names (I mean BGL, GLC, LIN) and also is hard to use this (FNR%22==0), because I have 5 BGL then 3 GLC then 4 LIN.

```
#!/bin/bash
awk '
FNR==1{
  ++count
  value=count"BGL" (or whatever)
}
{
  $1=value
}
1
FNR%22==0{
  ++count
  value=count"BGL"
}
' after_SOL.gro | tee after_SOL2.gro
```

I will also do this on many files, so I will pyt my script in for loop:

```
#!/bin/bash
for num in {1..100}; 
do 
    (awk script here) eq4_$num.gro | tee eq5_$num.gro
done
```

Comment: Can you explain in word what the difference is between your input and your output?

Comment: Yes in the first colum I have in input: 1BGL..2GLC..3LIN..4LIN..and again 1BGL..2GLC..3LIN..4LIN..and again 1BGL..2GLC..3LIN..4LIN. In output I want to have 1BGL..1GLC..1LIN then 2BGL..2GLC..2LIN then 3BGL..3GLC..3LIN etc

Comment: you want to `sort`?, you do not need awk to do that....

Comment: No I dont want to sort. I want to rename first column in every atom (every atom is one line). Sort is useless in that case, I have 900 molecules, so I need to have 1 BGL/GLC/LIN, 2 BG/GLC/LIN, 3 BGL,GLC/LIN 4, 5, 6 BGL/GLC LIN  etc.  Now I have 1BGL everywhere, 2 GLC everywhere, 3 LIN everywher and 4 LIN everywhere. But you're right. Maybe first I should sort so I will have for example 10 thousand lines of BGL, then 20 thousand lines of GLC and 50 thousand lines of LIN, and then I will use script, which I paste here, so I can use for example if (NR>=3 && NR<=20000) FNR%22==0{
  ++count etc

Comment: you failed to define `atom`, but i guess its 'BGL','GLC',LIN',etc..

Comment: If you provide 5 or 6 lines of simple input/output instead of 100 or whatever number that is in your question then you'll get more people willing to try to understand your example so they can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this script does exactly what you want and preserves the tabular formatting of the input:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
awk '
NR <= 2 {print} /* skip two lines of headers */
NR > 2  {
  sub(/[0-9]*/, "", $1); 
  if ($1 != prev) {count[$1]++} 
  prev = $1
  printf ("%8s %6s %4s %7s %7s %7s\n", count[$1]$1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6)
} ' data.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

This script should renumber molecules.

```
#!/usr/bin/gawk -f
BEGIN{ mol=""; prev=""; }
{
        gsub(/[0-9]/,"",$1);
        mol=$1;
        if (mol==prev){
                nr=m[mol];
        }
        else {
                nr=++m[mol]
        };
        prev=mol;
        print nr$0
}
```

Every molecule ('BGL','GLC',LIN') sequence number is kept in an array `m[]`. And incremented on change of the molecule.

I hope this is what where are planning to do?